# Update certain values in update request

Tags: go, rethinkdb

i've a notification list, i would like update their status as read

**Notification struct** :

```
type Notification struct {
    Id string `gorethink:"id,omitempty"`
    UserId string
    Content string
    Read bool
    CreatedAt time.Time
}
```

in my handle function to get notification i put something like this :

```
func getLastNotifications(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
     ret := notification.getLastNotification()
     userId := getCurrentUserId()

         go func(){
            r.Table("Notifications").Filter(r.Row.Field("UserId").Eq(userId)).Update(func(term r.Term) r.Term{
        //And here i would like only update each Notification with {Read: true}
    })
}()


     RenderJSON(http.StatusOK, ret)
}
```

As explained in the code I will wish to update **Read** to **true** in each **Notification** belonging to the user.

So how can i do that ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the following query to update all of a users posts to read:

```golang
r.Table("Notifications").Filter(r.Row.Field("UserId").Eq(userId)).Update(map[string]interface{}{"read": false})
```

I hope this helps!